# Error in print prdf. Undefined property $_localeResolver

Tags: magento2

I am facing the below issue in print sales pdf in magento2 after upgrading the magento version.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: 
InvoicePdfimage\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice::$_localeResolver 
in /InvoicePdfimage/Model/Magento/Sales/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/module/etc/di.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\module\Model\Order\Pdf\InvoicePdf"/>
</config>
```

Now you can create Vendor\module\Model\Order\Pdf\InvoicePdf.php file & add the below code,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\module\Model\Order\Pdf;

use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice;

class InvoicePdf extends Invoice
{
    public function getPdf($invoices = []) {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();

            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());

            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );

            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());

            $this->_drawHeader($page);

            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }

            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
            $this->drawNotice($page);
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }


    protected function drawNotice(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page) {
        $iFontSize = 10;     
        $iColumnWidth = 520; 
        $iWidthBorder = 260;
        $iXCoordinateText = 30;
        $sEncoding = 'UTF-8';
        $this->draw -= 10;
        try {
            $oFont = $this->_setFontRegular($page, $iFontSize);
            $iXCoordinateText = $this->getAlignCenter($sNotice, $iXCoordinateText, $iColumnWidth, $oFont, $iFontSize); 
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(1, 0, 0));                                             
            $iXCoordinateBorder = $iXCoordinateText - 10;                                                               
            $page->drawLine($iXCoordinateBorder, $this->draw, $iXCoordinateBorder + $iWidthBorder, $this->draw);
            $this->draw -= 15;                                                                                             
            $page->drawText($sNotice, $iXCoordinateText, $this->draw, $sEncoding);
            $this->draw -= 10;
            
            $page->drawLine($iXCoordinateBorder, $this->draw, $iXCoordinateBorder + $iWidthBorder, $this->draw);
            
            $this->draw -= 10;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        }
    }

    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

        // custom column

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what was the error ?